# Neo4j: Multiple Relationships Merge Issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I've a neo4j schema in which I've 3 nodes. e.g. p,b,c

I want to write a Merge query such that

```
MERGE (p)-[:has_b]->(b),
MERGE (p)-[:has_c]->(c1),
MERGE (p)-[:has_c]->(c2)
```

where c1 and c2 are instance of c node having different property values.

i.e. Merge on all three relationships.

If any of 3 merge queries creates a new node, all relationships should use newly created p node.

I can achieve this if I had only two relationships using

```
(c)<-[:has_c]-MERGE (p)-[:has_b]->(b)
```

Any suggestions how to do it for 3 relationships as in my case?

FYI, I'm using py2neo which isn't helping at all.

Answer (score 0):

Nodes don't have instances. A node is a node and it has a label.

You can `MERGE` your nodes first to make sure they exist and that all relationships use the same `p`:

```
MERGE (p:LabelA {k: "v"})
MERGE (b:LabelB {k: "v"})
MERGE (c1:LabelC {k: "v"})
MERGE (c2:LabelC {k: "v"})
MERGE (p)-[:has_b]->(b)
MERGE (p)-[:has_c]->(c1)
MERGE (p)-[:has_c]->(c2)
```

This will create the nodes and relationships only once.

Comment: this will fetch p node having {k:v}, that may or may not having has_b/has_c relationships. Basically, I want p node to check it's relationships with b, c1 and c2 and return the old p node if all three relationships exist and have same properties, and create a new node even if any one of three relationships are new (if property of end_node is different, relationship name can be same). Do let me know if you want me to explain more.

Comment: similar to what (c:LabelC {c:'d'})<-[:has_c]-MERGE (p:LabelP {p:'q'})-[:has_b]->(b:LabelB {b:'b'}) provides. But this is for only two realtionships. I want this functionality for 3 realtionships

Comment: basically i want MERGE query for 3 relationships in one query

Comment: Don't get it. They query I posted *does* `MERGE` 3 relationships. It will return the old p if existing or create a new one. The query you mention in your second comment does not make sense, what is the `MERGE` doing?

Comment: sorry query in 2nd comment should be MERGE (c:LabelC {c:'d'})<-[:has_c]-(p:LabelP {p:'q'})-[:has_b]->(b:LabelB {b:'b'})

Comment: Just do it separately. And note that `MERGE` might create duplicate nodes when used with complex patterns: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html#merge-merge-on-a-relationship-between-an-existing-node-and-a-merged-node-derived-from-a-node-property

Comment: I'm okay with duplicate p nodes. Need merge query for a node having 3 relationships